# Julia dot operator and boolean

Tags: boolean, julia

Suppose I have `p = [true, true, false, false]` and `q = [true, false, true, false]`.  How can I logically "and" them, say like 
`p .&& q`?

Answer (score 3):

Use `.&` instead:

```
julia> p=[true, true, false, false]
4-element Array{Bool,1}:
 1
 1
 0
 0

julia> q=[true, false, true, false]
4-element Array{Bool,1}:
 1
 0
 1
 0

julia> p .& q
4-element BitArray{1}:
 1
 0
 0
 0
```

You have to be careful though as `&` works also on non-`Bool` elements:

```
julia> [11,12,13] .& [3,2,1]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 0
 1
```

Comment: To expand on what's going on: with `.&`, you are [broadcasting](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting-1) the "and" operation element-wise. Broadcasting is a very powerful syntax and composes very nicely as your code gets more complex.

Comment: In the second part of Bogumil's answer, where he cautions against what happens when not applying it to boolean data: that example is showing what happens when you compare the actual bits that form `11` and `3`... in other words you are comparing each bit in `...1011` (eleven) and `..0011` (three) and getting `..0011` (three) as first result.

Comment: You could type your arrays as `p = Bool[true, true, false, false]`, specially if they are created empty `Bool[]` and then you start filling them. This will make them only accept bools, you would need to transform non bools into bools if that is your intention, ie: `bool(x::Int) = x == 0 ? false : true`

Comment: I made this comment as it is a common mistake - e.g. people work with DataFrames.jl take some column, say `:a`, from it - they think its `eltype` is `Bool` and they do `.&` on it, but in consequence they get a wrong result silently (and they learn about it much later).